# Regex, trouble with geographic coordinate system values (seconds), Java

Tags: java, regex

For example, I have a String from CSV `"XX","00° 00' 00,00" n.","00° 00' 00,00" e.","YYY°"`.
How can I with regex parse this string into this:

`"XX"
"00° 00' 00,00" n."
"00° 00' 00,00" e."
"YYY°"`

I've used this regex `line.split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)")`, but it turned out, that it parses like this:

`"XX"
"00° 00' 00,00" n.,00° 00' 00"
"00" e"
"YYY°"`

and following question:
how to replace **ONLY** first and last double quotes? It must look like this:

`XX
00° 00' 00,00" n.
00° 00' 00,00" e.
YYY°`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
String[] result = line.substring(1, line.length() - 1).split("\",\""));
```

The substring will remove the first and last `"` character and then you split by `","` pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use Regex, you might as well just use capturing groups to get the final result. I tested this pattern on RegexPlanet.com and it produces what you need.

```
Pattern.compile("\"(\\w+)\"\\s*,\\s*\"(\\d+°\\s+\\d+'\\s+\\d+(?:[\\.,]\\d+)(?:''|\")\\s+[nNsS]\\.)\"\\s*,\\s*\"(\\d+°\\s+\\d+'\\s+\\d+(?:[\\,]\\d+)(?:''|\")\\s+[eEwW]\\.)\"\\s*,\\s*\"(\\w+°)\"");
```

This is WITH string escaping. After you call `find` on the matcher, you can get them with `group(n)` as you've specified. This also presumes some optionality in whether you're sent double-quotes or two single ones for the seconds, and doesn't assume you'll always have floating points for them, nor which delimiter will be used.

When using constant regular expressions that don't change from the user data, it's generally a good idea to have them as compiled constants in static fields, because their compilation impacts performance.

If this looks scary, you should just practice your patterns more with an online tool like [RegexPlanet](http://www.regexplanet.com) and just play around with them to try different stuff.

Comment: Cool, but I have got about 50 possible values in my String to split. That's a case :)